# access apache localhost from another Personal-Computer in the same local network

Tags: php, windows, apache, localhost

- Operating system : **windows 7**
- Apache version  : **2.2** -  for win32 from : [ appserv.org ]
- Network : **Local Connection**
- ..............................................
- Example for the Requirement Question **:**

  ---

  [image]

how i can do that ?

> include detail explanation if you can.

Comment: Configure the server machine's firewall to allow incoming calls on port 80, find out its local IP address, e.g. 192.168.1.1 or something like that, then you can access the server from other computers on the same network using the IP, e.g. http://192.168.1.1/SimpleSite.php

Comment: Yes, that should work. You probably want to make sure the server always has the same IP, using your router's config

Comment: @PatrickHund > i'll try it . thanks for the info :)